# Remount shared folder: alternative to mount -a

Tags: mount, samba, fstab

Some shared folders unexpectedly get unmounted sometimes, therefore I've scheduled a `mount -a` with the purpose of remountig **only** those shared folders that got unmounted in the meantime.

In the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man8/mount.8.html), however, I read:

> Note  that it is a bad practice to use **mount -a** for fstab checking.
>   The recommended solution is **findmnt --verify**.

It is my understanding that `findmnt --verify` checks **all** mounted filesystems, and does not perform any further action. I would like to only check **cifs** mounts and remount them if any error is encountered.

What is the preferred way to accomplish this?

---

**Edit:**

Thanks to [Soren A](https://askubuntu.com/users/614422/soren-a) for pointing out how to filter only `cifs` filesystems: `findmnt -t cifs --verify`.

**Update:**

I added a line in my `/etc/fstab` and `findmnt --verify` did not detect it as being unmounted. It thus seems ineffective at detecting unmounted entries in `/etc/fstab`. Maybe I just mistook *fstab checking* for *checking whether all entries in fstab are correctly mounted* instead of just *verify /etc/fstab parsability and usability*.

Comment: Look at `man findmnt` ... it seems that -t or --types list takes a comma seperated list of filesystem types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have misunderstood the meaning of the `mount` [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man8/mount.8.html):

> it is a bad practice to use mount -a for **fstab checking**.

Maybe because this is what I was looking for, I took it to mean: *checking whether all entries in fstab are correctly mounted*.

Instead, the `findmnt` [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/findmnt.8.html) says:

> -x, --verify
>   Check mount table content. The default is  to  **verify  /etc/fstab  parsability**  and usability.

So, it seems `findmnt --verify` is just meant to check the correctness of `/etc/fstab`, regardless of the current state of mounted filesystems.